# Pymongo: how to get the value of a specific field

Tags: python, pymongo

I have the document below. I would like to get the topic field if the password matches.

> email: "info@info.com"
>   first_name: "james"
>   password: Binary('HcM0Js5Pqh8oGZxLSNuMJNgb5l1WUCn5NRhB/L4juIY=')
>   surname:"mcarthy" 
>   topic: "journalism"

I am using below code to check if the key exists.

```
    user = user_in_db.find_one({'password': key})
    if user is None:
```

How can i retrieve the topic field if the user does exist?

Comment: have you tried `user.topic` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is very simple. As per this official [tutorial](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html), the return of `find_one` is a dictionary, hence you could do something like:

```
user = user_in_db.find_one({'password': key})
if user:  # check if user exists
    topic = user['topic']
```